# Routing traffic on a host connected to three subnets

Tags: networking, routing

I have a host with three network interfaces. Each interface is connected to a separate network and one of those networks contains another gateway that can reach the outside world. My goal is to have all networks communicate with each other through the host (they must communicate through the host as there is no other network path between the networks).

Host:

- 192.168.50.1/24
- 192.168.60.1/24
- 10.50.52.110/23

Gateway:

- 10.50.52.1/23

Client1:

- 192.168.50.2/24

Client2:

- 192.168.60.2/24

Currently, the host can ping everything. Client1 and client2 can ping all interfaces on the host as well as each other, but neither client can ping 10.50.52.1 or reach the internet. The three networks can only reach each other through the host. Below is the routing table of the host. Any comments or suggestions would be appreciated. I'm especially confused by how the clients are able to ping each other but not 10.50.52.1.

```
root@Host:~# route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
192.168.60.2    192.168.60.1    255.255.255.255 UGH   0      0        0 eth2
192.168.50.2    192.168.50.1    255.255.255.255 UGH   0      0        0 eth1
10.50.52.1      10.50.52.110    255.255.255.255 UGH   0      0        0 eth0
192.168.50.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth1
192.168.60.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth2
10.50.52.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.254.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
0.0.0.0         10.50.52.1      0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
root@Host:~#
```

Comment: Have a look at [NAT](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-forward-ports-through-a-linux-gateway-with-iptables) (skip the part installing nginx and read it all bevor starting). I think you are able to ping the 10.50.52.1 but it doesn't know where to send the response

Comment: @derHugo, you're absolutely right! 10.50.52.1 has no clue where the client networks are. A simple NAT worked well as I don't have any machines outside of the client networks that need to originate connections. The specific commands to enable NAT were: 
"iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE"
"iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0 -o eth1 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT"
"iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0 -o eth2 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT"

Comment: Hey glad you figured it out on your own. It's the best way to actually learn how it works ;)